# Scrollbooster carousel inside a Bootstrap 5 modal don't scroll

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-modal, carousel, bootstrap-5

Im trying to create a carousel with the js library Scrollbooster inside a bootstrap modal.

```react
import React from "react";
import ScrollBooster from "scrollbooster";

export default class ChannelPage extends React.Component{

  //Creates the scrollbooster instace that turns #slideViewport and it's content into a carousel
  componentDidMount(){
    const carousel = new ScrollBooster({
      viewport: document.getElementById("slideViewport"),
      content: document.getElementById("slideContent"),
      direction: "horizontal",
      scrollMode: "transform",
    });
  }

  render(){

    return(

      <section id="channelInfoTab">
        
        {/* Bootstrap Modal */}
        <div>
          <div className="modal" tabIndex="-1" id="modal">
            <div className="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-dialog-scrollable">
              <div className="modal-content">
                <div className="modal-body">

                  {/* The actual carousel */}
                  <div id="slideViewport">

                    <div id="slideContent" className="hstack"> 
                      <img src="/assets/brand_icons/whatsapp.png" alt="ws" />
                      <img src="/assets/brand_icons/whatsapp.png" alt="ws" />
                      <img src="/assets/brand_icons/whatsapp.png" alt="ws" />
                      <img src="/assets/brand_icons/whatsapp.png" alt="ws" />
                      <img src="/assets/brand_icons/whatsapp.png" alt="ws" />
                      <img src="/assets/brand_icons/whatsapp.png" alt="ws" />
                      <img src="/assets/brand_icons/whatsapp.png" alt="ws" />
                      <img src="/assets/brand_icons/whatsapp.png" alt="ws" />
                      <img src="/assets/brand_icons/whatsapp.png" alt="ws" />
                      <img src="/assets/brand_icons/whatsapp.png" alt="ws" />
                      <img src="/assets/brand_icons/whatsapp.png" alt="ws" />
                      <img src="/assets/brand_icons/whatsapp.png" alt="ws" />
                      <img src="/assets/brand_icons/whatsapp.png" alt="ws" />
                      <img src="/assets/brand_icons/whatsapp.png" alt="ws" />
                      <img src="/assets/brand_icons/whatsapp.png" alt="ws" />
                      <img src="/assets/brand_icons/whatsapp.png" alt="ws" />
                    </div>

                  </div>

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

          <div id="channelDataContainer">

            {/* When you click here the modal shows up */}
            <div className="d-flex" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modal">
              <p id="description" className="text-truncate">description</p>
            </div>

          </div>
          
      </section>
    )
  }
}
```

The problem it's that the carousel dont scroll. I know the ScrollBooster istance it's created correctly because the carousel have bounce effect. But it dont scroll.

When I put the carousel outside of the modal it works well, but inside it just breaks. I think the problem has to do with the css atributes that bootstrap asssign to the modal components. I've tried play with the modal's css attributes with the chrome's debugtools looking to find the attribute that breaks the carousel but i can't find it.